# Package iOS iPad application for company with 10 employees

Tags: ios, ipad, software-distribution, iphone-developer-program

I would like to distribute the application I have created to a company who have 10 employees only and wont extend past 20.  The application will be in-house and will not be sold on the app store or anywhere else.

Is there a way to be able to distribute the application without having to add each individual's UDID in the Testing provisioning section in the developers portal as from what I understand is only used for testing purposes.

If anyone could give me a clear guide on how I am able to distribute the application with ease so that I can just install the app on the 10 iPad devices. The goals are:
1) to be able to send application updates every other week and make it easy for them to download. 
2) to be able to add a new device when a new employee joins the company.

So far I have been using testflight to allow my beta tester to have a go at my application and i was about to add the 10 employees in a similar fasion but I dont think this would be the right way, although the advantage using testflight is the ability to send applications with ease to users.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to distribute my apo wirelessly. The application would check for the current version by analysing a plist file stored on the server, and if the ipad's software version was lower than that of the plist file version key then the application would swivel to the download page of the new ios application. it works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

If your client can afford the big $300 per year, you can have them get into Apple's "Enterprise" program ([described here](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)) where they have [some handy utilities and techniques you can use](http://www.apple.com/business/accelerator/deploy/app-distribution.html).

Comment: Thanks for replying michael. Could you suggest other solutions one that avoids having to pay $300?